# Text formatting from MYSQLI-query

Tags: php, text-formatting

I basically have been forced to learn SQL-programming from scratch to be able to complete a project I have been developing. With the help of the internet, and especially this site, I have been able to create a php-routine where I can choose data from my DB using drop downs. The results are then stored into a new table and what really bugs me is that I can`t wrap my head around how to display the results properly. What I am asking is how can I easily format the table so that the text is alligned as looks better on the eye?

I uploaded the file to this URL to show what my problem is: http://fantasysoccerpro.com/99.php

I want all four categories: POSITION, PLAYER, SALARY and PROJECTION to be alligned under each other on each line.

```
<?php
session_start();

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost",".....",".....",".....");
//or die ('unable to connect');

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

//SHOW TEAM//

$sql = "SELECT * FROM 1dzzdp";

mysqli_select_db($con,'.....');
$retval = mysqli_query( $con, $sql );
if(! $retval )
{
die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
echo "{$row['POSITION']}  ".
"{$row['PLAYER']}  ".
"{$row['SALARY']}  ".
"{$row['PROJECTION']}".
"{$row['SUM']} <br> ";

}
```

Comment: show us the expected results/formatting. Far as I could see, everything is under a new line.

Comment: That looks like tabulated data, so wrap some HTML around it, probably a `<table>`

Comment: This is how I want it to look: http://fantasysoccerpro.com/formatted.jpg

Comment: then you can either seperate by `\t` (tab delimited) or use tables as stated by @RiggsFolly above.

Comment: Sidenote: You don't need this `mysqli_select_db($con,'.....');` you already declared 4 parameters in your initial connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is to wrap all that in a HTML table

```
echo '<table>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo '<tr>';

    echo '<td>' . $row['POSITION'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['PLAYER'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['SALARY'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['PROJECTION'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['SUM'] . '</td>';

    echo '</tr>';
} 
echo '</table>';
```

Of course you may then need to do some formatting using some CSS.

Comment: Thanx a lot - I really appreciate it!